# correct usage with commas (dashes)

Tags: american-english, british-english

1.The actor, a life well lived, died on the stage.

2.The victim, a local solicitor, was killed on impact.

Is it acceptable to use commas with 1, like 2, or should em dashes be used with after.

The actor — after a life well lived — died on the stage.

Comment: In principle you could use dashes (or brackets) instead of commas to delineate the "parenthetical" clause in both / all three examples. Note that the ***first*** one is a slightly different construction (it's not that the actor ***is*** "a life well lived" - that's an ***attribute***, referring to the fact of him having done something), and it's a significantly more "stylized, literary" usage than the second.

Answer (score 1):

[The *em-dash* can replace parenthesis, commas, and also colons.](https://www.really-learn-english.com/em-dash.html) That said, you can simply *replace* the commas with the dashes. There is *no need* to add any word (in your example, 'after'). The [non-restrictive clauses](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/non-restrictive_clauses.htm) with double commas (example number -2) can be replaced by em-dashes.

Nevertheless, as FumbleFingers pointed out, the first example does not mean that the actor *is* a life well-lived.